# CkEditor 4 Custom Line Height Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor4.x

I am using CkEditor 4 for my web project. I have managed to fully integrate the editor as well as the external line-height plugin from `https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lineheight` to adjust the line-height for the text. The default line height works well. However, I am facing one challenge. When I modify the line height as per the documentation provided using the `em`, the line height does not change. It just remains the same. I have tried to edit my `config.js` file but nothing has happened. Research has not proven fruitful as well. Could somebody help me out please. I need to have an option with 0em, 1em, 2em, etc for line height.

**My config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
      config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight';
      config.uiColor = '#ced4da';
      config.line_height="1em;1.1em;1.2em;1.3em;1.4em;1.5em";
};
```

My snippet html file is as follows:

```
<div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80">This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor 4.</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(event){
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
});
```

Could somebody help me to configure the custom line-height options.

As per the official documentation, this is the information

```
Customizing the lineheight values in the dropdown
-------------------------------------------------------
In order to have custom values of line-height instead of the default, you can add following line in the config.js file:
    
    config.line_height="1em;1.1em;1.2em;1.3em;1.4em;1.5em";
    
    Here, "em" is the unit of line-height which you can change to "px","%" or any other allowed unit for line-height. 
    You can also change the numbers based on your requirements. You can have more range or low range , it all depends on your requirements.
```

Answer (score -1):

Thought its an issue as well, but guess what, it's not.

Just change the line-height values (if you're using px measurement) to bigger values, so you can see the actual change.

For example:

```
line_height: '1px;10px;20px;30px;40px;50px',
```